# Raster extraction doesn't show up under QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I need to apply the raster extraction tool in QGIS.
But the Raster extraction option does not show up under the RASTER tab.

I believe this is part of the rgdalTools plugin but I can't find this in the plugins download list.

Using QGIS 3.10.1 (Coruna)

Tips?

Answer (score 3):

Raster extraction is located under Processing toolbox. If you write extraction at the search area of the Processing toolbox, you will find Raster extraction:

[image]

The [QGIS help](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html) page shows that Raster extraction is part of the QGIS 3.10, and the algorithm is derived from the GDAL grid utility.

I am using QGIS version 3.10.7 Coruña for your reference.